# Fastest algorithm to find regions containing arbitrary point

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor

A `Region` is a subset of the plane that is defined by connecting a set of points so that they form a closed polygon. It can be assumed to be convex.

We can assume that given an aribraty point there is a method to check if the point is inside this region or not.

```
class Region{
   std::vector<double> x;
   std::vector<double> y;

   bool IsPointInside(double x, double y); // assume this is implemented
}
```

The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

Given an arbitrary number of `Region`s existing in the plane, given a point obtain which regions the point lies into. My goal is to implement a performant algorithm to solve this, being able to compute some kind of auxiliary data structure ahead of time in order to speed lookup.

My attemps:

1. Naive approach: iterating over all regions to check if the point lies on the region or not. This will work but has the worst performance
2. Create a grid: fixing some `spacing` parameter to a very low value, create a grid of points and build a map to associate each point to the list of regions it lies into. This will take some time but it will only be computed once. After this has been done, giving an arbitraty point I Compute the closest point in the grid to it using a fast algorithm such as kd-tree and return the regions from the initial mapping. This works but can return erroneous results if the grid spacing is not low enough.
3. Iterate over all regions and compute the smallest circle that contains this region. Get the maximum of these radius `R` and compute a grid using the centers of these circles. Given an abitrary point, find all points in the grid closer than `R`. For all these regions, manually check if the point is inside or not.

I think solution number 3 would be performant enough but I am asking this question in case someone can discuss a more appropiate algorithm for this problem (maximizing for lookup speed).

Answer (score 2):

Like any other performance question, the "fastest" method is going to depend on the implementation details. With that caveat, I can offer some observations and point to some prior work on this problem.

This is a common operation in computer graphics, so there has been a lot of work done in this area.

I think you want to create some type of auxiliary [space-partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) data structure like a [`k-d`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). The auxiliary data structure will allow for very quick testing of which `Regions` possibly cover a point and then use the more expensive intersection test on only those `Regions`.

Again, without the specifics about the problem and implementation, it is impossible to give the optimal solution, I think the following strategy would work well under a number of different scenarios.

Map the original polygons to the corresponding set of possibly overlapping covering rectangles. Split any overlapping rectangles into mutually exclusive non-overlapping rectangles keeping track of the `Regions` each rectangle represents.

Construct a `k-d` tree representing the rectangles. Given a point to test, look up the possible intersecting `Regions` in the `k-d` tree and apply the more expensive polygon test to just those `Regions`.

Answer (score 2):

The name of your problem is "point location".

If you don't need to worry about regions changing, the [slab decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Slab_decomposition) can be very performant.

You decompose the plane into vertical (or horizontal) "slabs", using every point in every shape, and every intersection point, as a division.  The result is that, within each slab, the order of the regions *does not change*.  The polygon lines all go from one side of the slab to the other, and they don't cross.  The slab is divided into cells, where each cell is within some set of regions.

If you store the slabs in a binary search tree or ordered list, and then do the same for the cells in each slab, then you can locate a point in O(log n) time, just by searching for the slab, and then the cell.

The problem with a slab decomposition is that it can take O(n<sup>2</sup>) memory.  If that's a problem, then you can compress it by attempting to reuse subtrees across slabs if they have the same sequence of dividing lines.  If you're constructing the decomposition with a [sweep-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) algorithm (recommended), then you can use [persistent red-black trees](https://abhiroop.github.io/Haskell-Red-Black-Tree/#:%7E:text=A%20red%20black%20tree%20is,search%20%2C%20insert%20and%20delete%20operations.) inside each slab, and then you only pay for the changes between slabs instead of making all new trees.  That works well in many cases, but not all.  It's fine if you don't have a lot of region overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your regions & points by x-coordinates, where for regions we care about their extreme coordinates & whether we're entering or leaving the x-coordinates of the region. This takes O(n log n) for n = |points| + |regions|.

Parse this sorted array, keeping track of the currently-open regions (i.e. those where we've parsed one but not both extreme x-coordinates). On encountering a point, we associate it with the currently open regions. So map point -> set of regions.

Ditto for y-coordinates, but with a separate point map.

Now for each point, we take the intersection of the two associated sets of regions to get candidate regions for each point.

Finally, now that we've (hopefully) reduced the number of regions associated with each point, check each candidate region for each point.

How efficient is this? Well, it's possible to construct a set of points & regions where every point is in every set-intersection, so in the worst case this is identical to your naive solution. On the other hand, it might be a practical solution for you depending on the data set you're working with.